# OSX Second Keyboard

Tags: macos, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

Adobe Lightroom and Ableton Live are two applications that really benefit from keyboard shortcuts.  I got an Apple Bluetooth Keyboard with the intention of using it for dedicated shortcut keys for either of these apps.

Unforuntately I didn't consider the obvious: OSX treats them both as a single keyboard; for example, key <kbd>G</kbd> on the bluetooth is the same as key <kbd>G</kbd> on the internal.

How can I have my apps distinguish between keyboards?  Preferably something that can be configured to work with any application that accepts keyboard shortcuts.

http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=2008081918101840 suggests keeping <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> on one keyboard, but this poses a problem of flexibility, and some apps cannot distinguish between uppercase and lowercase keystrokes.